# Why doesn't this system wide CBT hook work properly?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, hook

I am trying to create a system wide hook to monitor processes and terminate unwanted ones. I searched and found out I need to use CBT hooks, my first try failed and this is the second one, the former question can be [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565826/why-doesnt-setwindowshookex-accept-the-hook-procedure) though.

The following code builds just fine, but it seems the hooks are not even called, since I tried setting break point in the `DllMain()`, but I never reach there. Other functions seem to be accessible though!

Here are the code snippets:

**dllmain.cpp**

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <Windows.h>
using namespace std;

 HINSTANCE currentProcessHandle;
 HOOKPROC hkprcSysMsg;
 HHOOK hookID;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call, LPVOID lpReserved)
{
    std::ofstream outfile("test.txt");


    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        currentProcessHandle = hModule;
        break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK HookProcedure(int nCode, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam)
{
    std::ofstream outfile("test.txt");
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        switch (nCode)
        {
        case HCBT_CREATEWND:
            outfile << L"Created!~";
            cout << "Created!~" << endl;
            break;
        case HCBT_DESTROYWND:
            outfile << L"Destroied!~";
            cout << "Destroied!~" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "sth else" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(hookID, nCode, wparam, lparam);
    }
    outfile.close();
}

__declspec(dllexport) void InstallHook()
{
    hookID = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, HookProcedure, currentProcessHandle, 0);
}

__declspec(dllexport) void UnistallHook()
{
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookID);
}
```

And this is the **Consumer application**

```
// Hook Executer.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "..\Dll\dllmain.cpp"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int num = -1;
    cout << "1.Install Hook"<<endl
        << "2.Unistall Hook"<<endl
        << "0.Exit";
    do{
        cin >> num;
        if (num ==1)
        {
            InstallHook();

        }
        else
        {
            UnistallHook();
        }
        getchar();
        system("cls");
        cout << "1.Install Hook" << endl
            << "2.Unistall Hook" << endl
            << "0.Exit";
    } while (num != 0 && num < 3);


    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program there is no error, not even exceptions of any kind, it's as if there is no DLL or I have coded nothing inside that DLL. What's wrong with it?

Comment: :-) include "..\Dll\dllmain.cpp" is NOT the proper way to have a DLL. Do you have a Visual Studio Solution with 2 projects, one EXE and one DLL?

Comment: Yes i do,! if i dont do that how am i supposed to call the dll?

Comment: But your EXE doesn't call ANY DLL! You just included the DLL cpp source in your main EXE...

Comment: First Step: suppress the include "..\Dll\dllmain.cpp" line! and replace it by include "..\Dll\dllmain.h" In the header, declare InstallHook and UnistallHook with __declspec(dllimport)

Comment: I did and this is the result: http://pastebin.com/8Xg4uyiU 
Now my application doesn't run!   
It just crashes upon execution and says :The application was unablke o start correctly (0xc0000007b) .click ok to close the application)

Comment: i rebuild the solution and also removed the dllexport as shown here:http://pastebin.com/Z0vryTrZ  still nothing works! as if there is no hook!!!( the program runs fine but its not doing what it is supposed to be doing )

Comment: Look, you seem to don't know the basic of C programming with DLL, you will have a very hard time trying to use CBT Hooks. The pastebin you linked show a DllMain implementation in the header... I may post an answer I if i Have some time latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

implement your DLL code in a CPP file, not an header:

```
//dllmain.cpp
#include "stdafx.h" // include <Windows.h>
                    // and other std headers in stdafx.h, if not already done

HINSTANCE currentProcessHandle;
HHOOK hookID;

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved ) {

    if ( ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH )
        currentProcessHandle = hModule;
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK HookProcedure( int nCode, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam ) {

    if ( nCode < 0 ) return CallNextHookEx( NULL, nCode, wparam, lparam );

    std::ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open( "test.txt",          // replace with an absolute path
                  std::fstream::app ); // append mode
    if (nCode >= 0) {
        switch( nCode ) {
            case HCBT_CREATEWND:
                outfile << "Created!\n";
                break;
            case HCBT_DESTROYWND:
                outfile << "Destroyed!\n";
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    outfile.close();
    return 0;
}

void InstallHook( void ) {
    hookID = SetWindowsHookEx( WH_CBT, HookProcedure, currentProcessHandle, 0 );
}

void UninstallHook( void ) { // NEW NAME
    UnhookWindowsHookEx( hookID );
}
```

Declare the DLL APIs in a header file.

```
// dllapi.h
void InstallHook( void );
void UninstallHook( void ); // NEW NAME
```

Use a DEF file for exporting, add it to the DLL project

```
; Def file
EXPORTS
    InstallHook
    UninstallHook
```

In the EXE project, include ONLY the DLL header file

```
 #include "..\Dll\dllapi.h"
```

In the EXE project, go to `properties->Linker->Input->Additional dependencies` and add the lib file generated during the build of the DLL. Alternative: make the DLL a dependency of the EXE in the project dependencies of the Solution, and in the EXE properties, set Yes for `Linker->general->Use Library dependency Inputs`

Comment: Thanks a million it compiles and builds just fine, and now it creates the text file, but its empty! and nothing gets shown on the console (maybe dll doesnt support console windows?) what else should i do to get this to work?

Comment: I changed it so that it appends what it founds and now this is what i get in the text file :) 
5A4F1B9C
5A4F1B9C
5A4F1BB4
5A4F1BB4
5A4F1BB4
5A4F1B9C
5A4F1B9C
5A4F1B9C
5A4F1B9C
Thank you very much sir, i'll dig more to see what is causing this.
Got it , i removed the L and its working just fine :) awesome :)

Comment: Did you use an absolute path for the text file, as "c:\\temp\\test.txt" ?

Comment: Yes, i did just exactly what you suggested and it is now working like Mercedes benz :)

Comment: use wofstream, not ofstream, when writing L"string". Or don't prefix with L :-)